# $x^n y^n = (xy)^n$, proof exercise

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, exponentiation, real-numbers

As an exercise, I tried to prove the following theorem.
Please share your thoughts about what I wrote.
(The proof only uses the utensils which are listed below.)

---

### Theorem

\begin{equation*}
   x^n y^n = (xy)^n
   \qquad \qquad
   \forall
     n   \in \mathbb{N}, \;
     x,y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}

---

### Proof

First, introducing a predicate $P$ over $\mathbb{N}$, we rephrase the theorem as follows.
\begin{equation*}
    \forall
      n \in \mathbb{N}
    :
      P(n),
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    P(n) \quad := \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R} : x^n y^n = (xy)^n.
\end{equation*}

We prove the theorem by induction on $n$.

$\textbf{Basis: }$ $P(0)$

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
       x^0     y^0
  & = (x^0)   (y^0) && \\
  & = (1  )   (1  ) && | \text{ zero-th power definition (see utensils below)} \\
  & =  1 \cdot 1    && \\
  & =  1            && | \text{ multiplicative identity} \\
  & =  (xy)^0       && | \text{ closure u. m. & zero-th power d.} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

$\textbf{Inductive step: }$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \big( P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + 1) \big)$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
We assume $P(n)$.
Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
            x^{(n + 1)}             y^{(n + 1)}
  & = \big( x^{(n + 1)} \big) \big( y^{(n + 1)} \big) && \\
  & =     ( x^{n} x         )     ( y^{n} y         ) && | \text{ nonzero-th power d.} \\
  & =       x^{n} x                 y^{n} y           && | \text{ generalised a. l.} \\
  & =       x^{n} y^{n}             x     y           && | \text{ generalised c. l.} \\
  & =     ( x^{n} y^{n}     )       x     y           && | \text{ generalised a. l.} \\
  & = \big( (xy)^n      \big)       x     y           && | \text{ } P(n) \\
  & =       (xy)^n                 (x     y)          && | \text{ generalised a. l.} \\
  & =       (xy)^{(n + 1)}                            && | \text{ closure u. m. & nonzero-th power d.} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

QED

---

### Utensils

$\textbf{zero-th power definition: }$
$
   \forall
     x \in \mathbb{R}
   :
     x^0 := 1
$

$\textbf{nonzero-th power definition: }$
$
   \forall
     n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{R}
   :
     x^{(n + 1)} := x^{n} x
$

$\textbf{closure under multiplication: }$
$
   \forall
     x,y \in \mathbb{R}
   :
     xy \in \mathbb{R}
$

$\textbf{multiplicative identity: }$
$
   \forall
     x \in \mathbb{R}
   :
     1x = x
$

$\textbf{generalised associative law: }$ concerning $\mathbb{R}$, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Generalized_associative_law)

$\textbf{generalised commutative law: }$ concerning $\mathbb{R}$, $\dots$

Comment: It’s correct and extremely formal. If your aim was to write an extremely formal proof, I’d say you nailed it.

Comment: The appeal to the generalized commutative law is unnecessary; all you need is $x(y^n) = (y^n)x$.

Comment: Note: for some, the more formal the proof, the better. More formal often, but not always, means "less ambiguous". I say keep writing proofs like this, with all the quantifiers, definitions, etc. explicit. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "Is this correct?", the answer is yes.  :-)